# In Stata, how can I save estimates and std errors while running multiple regressions?

Tags: regression, stata, coefficients

I am using quite a big data set and would like to estimate the Fama French coefficients for two event windows for each ID. I am using the following code (`dummy_reg` allocates the observations to the respective event window):

```
sort ID dummy_reg count
by ID dummy_reg: reg ret_px Mkt_RF SMB HML
```

Furthermore, I would like to use the coefficients to compute deltas between the event windows; however, I don't know how to include saving/generating new variables in the estimation process.

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
by ID dummy_reg: reg ret_px Mkt_RF SMB HML & egen b_Mkt_RF=_b[Mkt_RF] & egen b_SMB=_b[SMB] & egen b_HML=_b[HML]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all forums supporting questions on software problems:

- Reproducible problems are strongly preferred. You don't give us your dataset or use a publicly available dataset to illustrate the problem. In this case the lack of a reproducible example does not bite hard, as errors can be identified, but in other problems it can be crucial, so please note for any future questions.
- A report such as "didn't work" is regarded as maximally uninformative. Naturally, you don't understand what is happening, but you should always report **exactly what happened**, e.g. what error message was produced, which you can just copy and paste.

The single command

```
by ID dummy_reg: reg ret_px Mkt_RF SMB HML & egen b_Mkt_RF=_b[Mkt_RF] & egen b_SMB=_b[SMB] & egen b_HML=_b[HML]
```

is syntactically incorrect and/or not what you want in several different senses. It could only arise from some very wild guesses.

1. Your `by:` prefix is legal given your prior sort but the `regress` command following would run through the distinct groups so defined and only the last set of regression results would be available in memory afterwards.
2. The logical operator `&` is for combining numerical arguments into expressions to be evaluated for truth or falsity; there is no sense in which it combines commands to be followed one after the other.
3. The `egen` calls following would all be quite illegal as they contain no `egen` function call.
4. Even if they were legal under #3, the second time each `egen` command was invoked under `by:` there would be a problem as the variable being named already exists.
5. Even if they were correct under #3 and #4, there would be a problem for you as at the end of the code, the variables so created could only contain the last set of coefficient estimates. Problem #3 could be fixed by using `generate` rather than `egen`, and different code too, but problems #4 and #5 would remain.

Fortunately, there is a simple way out of all this. You need [the `statsby` command](http://www.stata.com%5Chelp.cgi?statsby) to save `regress` results. If you want the coefficient estimates alongside the original dataset, use `merge`.

Your question names standard errors [of what?] but nothing in your code accesses standard errors; nevertheless they can also be saved using `statsby`.

I have focused here on the one piece of code you present. The rest of the question refers to economics details I don't understand. Like almost everyone on Stack Overflow, I am not an economist.

Comment: This has been extremely helpful and appreciated! Also, thank you for the recommendations in regards to further questions.